# Parse different timestamp formats in spark

Tags: .net, apache-spark

I have a csv file where some columns are timestamps with this format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' and other columns in the same .csv file where the timestamp format is 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'. 
On spark read csv file I tried something like this:

```cs
  SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .Builder()
                .AppName("Spark Project")
                .GetOrCreate();


                spark.Read()
               .Option("delimiter", fileconfig.FileLoaderColumnSeparator)
               .Option("header", hasHeader)
               .Option("inferSchema", true)
               .Option("TimeStampFormat", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
               .Option("TimeStampFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
               .Option("TreatEmptyValuesAsNulls", true)
               .Option("IgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace", true)
               .Option("IgnoreTrailingWhiteSpace", true)
               .Csv(path);
```

But in this way it only assumes as a timestamp the last TimestampFormat and the first one as string.
I also tried to do .Option("TimeStampFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") and .Option("TimeStampFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss, dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") but none of this options worked.
How can I parse this two types of timestampformats.

If I omit the option timestampformat all timestamps are saved as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to specify two timestamp formats while reading csv file, default `last timestamp format` will be used everything else will be `overwritten`.

> **`These are the possible options I could think of:`**

**`1.use withColumn while reading the csv file:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

spark.read().
    option("delimiter", fileconfig.FileLoaderColumnSeparator).
    option("header", hasHeader).
    option("inferSchema", true).
    option("TimeStampFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").
    option("TreatEmptyValuesAsNulls", true).
    option("IgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace", true).
    option("IgnoreTrailingWhiteSpace", true).
    csv(path).
    withColumn("<MM/dd/yyyy_field_name>",to_timestamp(col("<MM/dd/yyyy_field_name>","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

---

`read the csv file with one timestamp format:`

```
val df= spark.read().
    option("delimiter", fileconfig.FileLoaderColumnSeparator).
    option("header", hasHeader).
    option("inferSchema", true).
    option("TimeStampFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").
    option("TreatEmptyValuesAsNulls", true).
    option("IgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace", true).
    option("IgnoreTrailingWhiteSpace", true).
    csv(path)
```

**`2.Then using to_timestamp function change type to string to timestamp:`**

from spark >= 2.2

```
df.withColumn("<MM/dd/yyyy_field_name>",to_timestamp(col("<MM/dd/yyyy_field_name>","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

**`3.Using from_unixtime and unix_timestamp functions:`**

```
df.withColumn("<MM/dd/yyyy_field_name>",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("<MM/dd/yyyy_field_name>"),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp"))
```

**`4.Using unix_timestamp and casting to timestamp type:`**

```
df.withColumn("<MM/dd/yyyy_field_name>",unix_timestamp(col("<MM/dd/yyyy_field_name>"),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp"))
```

---

> **`More dynamic way:`**

```
#input dataframe
df.show()
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|                 dt|                st1|                dt1|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|12/12/2019 09:23:23|12/12/2019 09:23:23|12/12/2019 09:23:23|
|12/13/2018 12:23:23|12/13/2018 12:23:23|12/13/2018 12:23:23|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
#filter all matching rows starts with dt and cast to timestamp

val df2= df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("dt")).foldLeft(df)((df, c) => {
  df.withColumn(s"$c",unix_timestamp(col(s"$c"),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp"))
})

df2.show(false)

#dynamically changed the format and casted to timestamp for dt,dt1 columns.
//+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
//|dt                   |st1                |dt1                  |
//+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
//|2019-12-12 09:23:23.0|12/12/2019 09:23:23|2019-12-12 09:23:23.0|
//|2019-01-12 12:23:23.0|12/13/2018 12:23:23|2019-01-12 12:23:23.0|
//+---------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```